# Using JBuilder on Rails 6 API Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Right now i am doing a project using rails 6 api mode. I want to use jbuilder to organize json response and i got it works. But i need to add this line

```
render 'somethings/action.json.jbuilder'
```

in all actions on my controllers. Is there any way to get it works without using that line of code? I mean like non-api rails behave.

Comment: Do you set the request headers to json? Something like this: `"Accept": "application/json"`?

Comment: Can you add an example of the controller and an example of the request? You should not have to explicitly pass a path to the template at all if you are following the conventions. You also may want to consider that jBuilder is pretty slow compared to the alternatives.